# .htaccess redirection adds subfolder directory to URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'll just use variables since I need more reputation to post more than 2 urls.

Let $url = http://mywebsite.com

$rurl = https://mywebsite.com/test1

I want to add an htaccess redirection to my website so that when someone goes to $url (example) they will be redirected to $rurl

Basically, I want to redirect "any" url with $url domain to $rurl

I've tried using the normal redirect 301 method on htaccess. When going to the root drectory/site, it redirects correctly but when I try to go to $url/test I'm redirected to $rurl/test1/test

You'll notice that when redirecting, it appends the subfolder directory of the previous directory to the redirection directory. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test1/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /test1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/index.php [L]
```

I hope this will help you! Please change subdir and site.com with your details.

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` command links two path nodes together, you're better off with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?test1 /test1 [L,R=301]
```